# Connecting to an external SQLite database

Tags: java, android, web-services, sqlite

So I'm working on this project where I have to translate an IOS app into an Android app. Everything was going fine until I came to this. The original app updates the internal database with the database located lets say here: "http://somelocation/dbHandler.axd?SqliteDbVersion=0" and every time the version changes, the app must download the new version. My question is, is there anyway I can do this on Java. I'm kind of new to android, and I've never used web services before (I did some investigation and found that webservices is the way to do it, but I have no idea of where to start).

Thanks in Advice!